# Page refresh issue for angular app deployment on tomcat server

Tags: angular, tomcat, url-rewriting

I have deployed Angular2 and spring REST API project on Tomcat.

1. So for page refresh i have added rewrite.config in web-inf folder so
   it works for angular2 routing and refresh .But it returns rest api
   response as html (index.html contents )

contents of `rewrite.config`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|txt|ttf|json|woff|ico)$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html
```

2. in the second case I found another rewrite config which has following contents

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|txt|ttf|json|woff|ico).*$
   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]

   RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [L,QSA]

But it gives follwing error in browser console :

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:8082/anc/dist/vendors.min.js' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled. Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:8082/anc/dist/app.min.js' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

Can anybody has faced same issue?

Comment: were you able to get a solution?I m also facing the same issue